# Передача результата метода в качестве аргумента в зависимости от условия

Tags: java, тернарный-оператор

Как в зависимости от значения вызвать определенный метод?

Есть два метода, возвращающие результат: `create()` и `edit()`, один из которых нужно вызвать при определенном условии.

Например:

```java
if(a == 0) {
    create();
} else if(a == 1) {
    edit();
}
```

Но в данном случае происходит непосредственный вызов, а как передать это в аргумент какой-то функции?
JsonPath.parse(**create()**/**edit()**)...

Записать `JsonPath.parse(create())` и `JsonPath.parse(edit())` отдельно в if - не вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Сохраните результат в переменную:

```
if(a == 0) {
   result = create();
}
if(a == 1) {
   result = edit();
}
JsonPath.parse(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

С помощью тернарного оператора: `JsonPath.parse(a == 0 ? create() : edit());`.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!

Comment: @arni21 тогда можете оценить мой ответ и отметить как принятый.